# How can I make the top logo in a navigation drawer act properly as a button?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make the top logo of the nav drawer act as a button that takes me back to the first fragment of the app, but I can't seem to make the button work at all, not even for simple tasks, such as a toast. The app crashes upon opening the app, so I don't even get to try using the button.

This is the error I get: "*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference*"

The logo is declared as an ImageButton in XML and this is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


public ImageButton logo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set the initial fragment
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    logo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.main_icon);
    logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `ImageButton` is in the `NavigationView`'s header, and that the `NavigationView` has only one header `View`, you can call `findViewById()` on that.

```
logo = (ImageButton) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.main_icon);
```

Alternatively, since the `View` is an `ImageButton`, you could set an `onClick` attribute on the layout entry, and move your `onClick()` method to the `Activity`.

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/main_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_logo"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

If you choose this option, make sure to remove the `setOnClickListener()` call.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is it. Literally figured it out 15 minutes ago, but thanks anyway. Although i didn't think of setting the onClick attribute in XML, which i ended up using since it seems like the more organized way in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create view. Use this

```
 View view = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
 logo = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.main_icon);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The view you gave me doesn't link to the one in the onClick command, even though they have the same name. Can you also provide the last part of the code you think works?